# oracle multiple database link read only access error

Tags: database, oracle, dblink

The query is like this

```
select 1 from dual@link1
union 
select 1 from dual@link2
```

then i got the read only access error.

I have users in all those 3 databases and they are all read only users, so when i do the query "`select 1 from dual@link1`" then i got read only error, then i tried to change the query as

```
set transaction read only;
select 1 from dual@link1;
```

then it's solved.

then i tried the query as below:

```
select 1 from dual@link1
union 
select 1 from dual@link2
```

it error again, i am not sure why 1 link works but 2 links won't work.

any one knows?

Comment: Exactly what error do you get (including the ORA error code and full txt, and stack if there is one)? How are the DB links and users defined - can you add their creation DDL and any user grants to the question (masking passwords of course)?

Comment: Also what happens if you `set transaction read only` and run the second part, `select 1 from dual@link2`, on its own; does that also work? What about if you run either select individually without the `set transaction` - looks like the first part still errors? It isn't clear at the moment if the problem you're seeing is something to do with the second query/link, or only happens when you union both queries together. Might there be a logon trigger on link2's DB that tries to write something, perhaps?

Comment: this is in java jdbc call, the oracle error code is ora-16000 i remember.

Comment: when i ran either one of them, both will work, only when i ran them in one single query, it won't work. and the weird thing is when ran them in pl/sql or sql plus, it works, the user is read only user created by DBA, i can't grant any permission for it, DBA won't also.

Comment: we have many oracle instances with different names, if i don't run the set transaction read only, neither of them will work on some of the databases, but some will work, all of them are same , our user are all read only users, now some of the oracle, i can run the union with multiple links, some can't, but then use pl/sql or sqlplus, all works, not sure what i should do in java to solve this.

Comment: there should not be any triggers, as when one query doesn't work, it doesn't matter which link i am trying, as i said , there are about 9 oracle databases, and each one linked to other 8, so i randomly chose 2 then ran that union query on one db, if it works, then it works for any other 8 links, if it doesn't work, then none of other 8 links will work.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite a surprising limitation of having the database in read-only mode, and multiple dblinks involved.

When you have read from the first dblink, you should *close the current transaction* (!) and only then read from the second dblink. This obviously prevents you from having a SELECT that joins tables from both dblinks.

It is documented, but rather hard to find. In [Starting Up and Shutting Down](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/start.htm#ADMIN004) you can see:

> When executing on a read-only database, you must commit or roll back any in-progress transaction that involves one database link before you use another database link. This is true even if you execute a generic `SELECT` statement on the first database link and the transaction is currently read-only.

To reiterate the concept, if you have access to metalink, there is an oracle note in response to a customer which shows an example ([Document 1296288.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=443661602732695&parent=EXTERNAL_SEARCH&sourceId=HOWTO&id=1296288.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=i0h4jftu6_4)) clarifying the limitation

```
SQL> select * from emp@link_emp_chicago;
select * from emp@link_emp_chicago
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-16000: database open for read-only access
Solution

SQL> select open_mode,database_role from v$database;

OPEN_MODE DATABASE_ROLE
---------- ----------------
READ ONLY PHYSICAL STANDBY

SQL> select owner,db_link from all_db_links;

OWNER
------------------------------
DB_LINK

PUBLIC
LINK_EMP_CHICAGO

SQL> select * from emp@link_emp_chicago;
select * from emp@link_emp_chicago
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-16000: database open for read-only access

SQL> set transaction read only;


Transaction set.

SQL> select * from emp@link_emp_chicago;

EMPNO ENAME JOB MGR HIREDATE SAL COMM
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
DEPTNO
----------
7369 SMITH CLERK 7902 17-DEC-80 800 20

7499 ALLEN SALESMAN 7698 20-FEB-81 1600 300 30

7521 WARD SALESMAN 7698 22-FEB-81 1250 500 30
```

Just to speculate, the reason may be related to the fact that, in the [words of Tom Kyte](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:8908307196113)

> distributed stuff starts a transaction "just in case".